# Plugin 'unix_socket' is not loaded in Mysql after restoring backup from Mariadb

Tags: mysql, mariadb, unix-socket

I was using Mysql without any issues, I accidentally imported a backup from Mariadb to my Mysql database, but after the session has been expired, I cannot log in to Mysql command, Phpmyadmin, I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin 'unix_socket' is not loaded
```

and also when I open my projects, I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I opened the backup file which I accidentally restored, I saw this line that I think may cause the issue:

```
LOCK TABLES `user` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `user` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `user` VALUES ('localhost','root','*9CFBBC772F3F6C106020035386DA5BBBF1249A11','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','','','','',0,0,0,0,'unix_socket','','N','N'),('localhost','erp','*818D35E17EDCC5FB9EFE28A7813DB1D7ED1AB5A3','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','','','','',0,0,0,0,'','','N','N');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `user` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Why `Unix Socket` prevent me to login into Mysql and use it and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Shut down the server.

Start the server with `--skip-grant-tables` option.

Connect to the server, run

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = '' WHERE plugin = 'unix_socket';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Close the connection.

You should be able to connect normally after that.

---

[Unix socket plugin](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/unix_socket-authentication-plugin/) allows a local user to connect to the database server using system credentials. MySQL finds "something" in the plugin field and attempts to use it as an authentication plugin, but since the MySQL installation naturally does not have the plugin, authentication fails, and there is no fall-back to the password-based authentication, hence the problem.